# Accounting references in VBA for different versions of office

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

If users are on 64bit Office with Office 16 the below code works fine but how do I account for users on different versions and 32bit also?

```
Sub Add_References_Programmatically()
Dim VBAEditor       As Object
Dim vbProj          As Object
Dim chkRef          As Object

Set VBAEditor = Application.VBE
Set vbProj = ActivePresentation.VBProject

On Error Resume Next
    vbProj.References.AddFromGuid "{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 5, 0
On Error GoTo 0

For Each chkRef In vbProj.References
    If chkRef.Name = "Excel" Then
        GoTo CleanUp
    End If
Next chkRef

vbProj.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"

CleanUp:
Set vbProj = Nothing
Set VBAEditor = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You put the relevant code inside compiler directives.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/directives

Comment: Or use late binding (`GetObject(FName)` or `CreateObject(AppName)`). Then you bind to the names of functions at runtime. It is slower but usually so fast you don't notice.

Comment: Another reference to compiler directives that I like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/compiler-constants